# $\int \frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^n}dx$

Tags: integration

Let be $n\in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

Compute the following integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^n}dx$$

I obtained that for $$n=1$$ the value of the integral is $$\tan^{-1}x+C$$
and for $$n=2$$
$$x\left(\frac{1}{2\left(x^2+1\right)}+\frac{\tan \:^{-1}}{2x}\right)+C$$
How to do the rest of the cases?

Comment: Have you considered going back and rewarding all your previous answers with upvotes and accepting them?

Comment: Hi @winic92046, if you set $x = \tan \theta$, then the integral is $\int \left(\cos^{2n-2} \theta\right) d\theta$. Do you know how to integrate (even) powers of cosine?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to integrate powers of cosine... :(

Comment: Hi @winic92046 Have you tried googling this? It seems there are many online resources discussing integrating powers of cosine.